# How to print X-Runtime on Ruby on Rails's view?

Tags: ruby, http-headers, rack, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I wish to print the response time that is set by Rack::Runtime on my view.
I know we can get all of the HTTP headers by " curl -I *address* ".

[image]

However, the response object in Rails controller **only** contains several headers by default:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'X-Frame-Options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'X-XSS-Protection' => '1; mode=block',
  'X-Content-Type-Options' => 'nosniff'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no such way. The reason is

1. When Rack adds the `X-Runtime` header to the response, the view has already been rendered. This is obvious because if not, how could Rack tell how long the view rendering takes? So you can't insert the value into your view at server side.
2. At the time Javascript starts to run on a browser, the response that contains the HTML has already been consumed, and the headers of the response has been thrown. So you can't insert the value into your view at browser side either.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you have said. 

What is defeating my mind is this.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware
With the rack, we can print it out on the view.

How is that possible?

Comment: @JohnsonYeap Forgive my poor English. Rack middleware can do many things, for example log the process time of each request, but it just can't add this time to your view, because when Rack gets the time, the view has already been rendered (i.e. from a bunch of erb files that contains ruby snippets to a single HTML-formatted string, with all ruby snippets evaluated. That string will be served as response body).

Comment: I see. Is there an alternative way to print request response time on the view?

Comment: @JohnsonYeap Why do you want to do that? If just for development, then most browsers ships with a developer tool that can record every request for you. You can see request/response headers from there. For example, if you're using Google Chrome or Chromium, then you can press `F12` and then click the `Network` tab on it, from there you can choose the request you are interested in and inspect it.

Comment: Yeah, I do aware of that...

I am just exploring and trying new stuff..